# Max # of elements and dimensions supported by each data container in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am working on a project that requires the handling of relatively large datasets (multiple terabytes) and would like to know the answer to the following questions in order the make appropriate architectural and design decisions (i.e. mostly regarding the splitting of the datasets):

- What is the maximum number of **elements** that I can hold in each of the MATLAB [containers](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f2-47534.html) (I'm mostly interested in nD arrays and cells)
- What is the maximum number of **dimensions** supported by each container type.

Are there any hard limits? Is it possible to determine dynamic limits during execution? (i.e. dependent on memory availability?).

Do these limits depend on the architecture? (e.g. 64 vs 32 bits). I am especially interested in answers regarding 64 bit systems (on both Windows and Linux).

I couldn't find a good reference that covers the questions above, so any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This page](http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1100/1110.html) gives maximum sizes by platform and architecture for vectors. It seems they aren't hard limits but rather the largest vector that will fit in memory with the OS and other services.  I would imagine that cells have similar, if not the same, limits.

Comment: Thanks! I'll wait to see if anybody else can comment on  the largest # of dimensions before accepting a final answer, but that's very helpful already.

Answer (score 1):

The total number of elements in the array is given by the product of the size of each dimension. The link in David's answer tells you the maximum number of elements that can be accommodated in a real double precision array. An `nD` array, which is what you're interested in, is equivalent to a reshaped `1D` vector with the same number of elements.

So you can mix and match the number of elements and create as many dimensions as you want, subject to the following constraints.

1. `#i ∈ {1,2,..., M}`, where `M` is the maximum possible number of elemnts, `#i` is the size of dimension `i`
2. `∏#i=M`
3. `i ∈ {1,2,..., M}` (although this follows from the previous two, I thought I'd state it)

So for example, on my machine, `M ≈ 2^30`.

```
a=randn(2^30,1);%# create a column vector with 2^30 rows
a=reshape(a,2,2^29);%# reshape it into a 2D matrix with 2 rows and 2^29 columns
a=reshape(a,2*ones(30,1)');%# reshape it into a 30D array with 2 elements in each dimension
```

So a hard upper bound for the max number of non-singleton dimensions would be `log2(M)`, as inceasing the size of a dimension would reduce the number of dimensions.

Comment: Thanks @R.M. That helps a lot. Any references that support your answer?

Comment: no, not really. I'm not aware of a ready look up for that info. But you can reason out the 3 constraints above yourself and verify that they should hold in the non-trivial case (trivial being no dimensions or null vector). The upperbound that I gave just follows from logical reasoning for arrays without singleton dimensions, as the smallest positive integer other than 1, is 2. If you increase this, the number of dimensions _has_ to reduce to satisfy constraint 2.